# "Printf Parser":To output a substring within specified characters ("(" and ")") in Python

Tags: python, c, string, parsing, substring

I am creating a C printf parser in python.
I want to have a substring within ( and ).
For e.g. `subprf('printf("%d is %d %% happy.",a,b);')` should give me `"%d is %d %% happy."` How do i create this?
Also could someone give me suggestions to proceed with the parser?

Comment: In C or in Python? Have you heard about [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am creating C's printf function parser in python.

Comment: Python has a [nice support for regexps](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). But your task is really weird.

Comment: How much prior experience do you have with parsers? If none, [recursive descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) might be a good starting point.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Actually we are given a project to make a very minimal C interpreter which can declare & initialize variables, work on expressions and operate on the printf function. At one step in my code i want to use the mentioned substring.